# angularjs: Get height of element after scope variable change in link function

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a function (clicked) in link function

```
link: function (scope, el, attr, ctrl) {
    scope.isOpen = false;
    scope.clicked = function () {
        scope.isOpen = !scope.isOpen;
        var submenuElem = el[0].querySelector('.sidebar-submenu');
        if (scope.isOpen) {
            submenuElem.css('height', submenuElem.offsetHeight+'px');
        }
    };
}
```

And in template i use ng-class to change height of div to auto:

```
<div class="closedSubMenu sidebar-submenu" 
     ng-class="{'openedSubMenu' : isOpen}">
    <ul ng-transclude></ul>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.closedSubMenu {
    height: 0; 
    max-height: 0;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    border-width: 0;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out, max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out, max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out, max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out, max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.openedSubMenu {
    height: auto;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    max-height: 400px;
    border-color: #f6f7f8;
}
```

I want to set div height after isOpen variable is true and that influence on div classes.
In my code submenuElem.offsetHeight return 0

I want a way like:

```
$apply(function(){
    scope.isOpen = !scope.isOpen;
},10);
```

That is possible just in controller.

Comment: What if you remove `height: 0;` from `.closedSubMenu`, wouldn't that let max-height handle things for you?

Comment: Doesn't affect. I want to set height to real value not auto. When ng-class add openedSubMenu height change to auto (more than zero). Now i want get the height and set height property